# Tell chrome devtools to really stop at breakpoint in - no async callbacks in background

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, indexeddb

I have the pleasure of debugging a quite complex indexedDB application with lots of data involved. And there is a bug somewhere, but I can't really track it down, because if I stop at the point, when things get funny, it is of no use, because the data I see in dev-tools now, is not anymore the data it was, when he really stopped, because it has been allready partly changed by other functions called by other successful db events.
And I can't stop anymore at those functions either ...
Not cool.

So in short, how to tell chrome to really stop(or queue in the background) everything, when I stop to debug?

edit:
so chrome is actually supposed to stop?
definitely not for me.
I see it on many things. 
Timestamp for example. there is a console log just before the breakpoint and the time there is older than other callbacks which will show up later on the console(and shouldn't)
Also he should stop on exceptions thrown later as well on many explicit "debugger" statements which gets all ignored and just processed and logged to the console

Also I see the DOM changes, from other callbacks later

So a chromebug just for me?
well, I tried with chromium on archlinux, as well with chrome on windows...

Comment: Chrome really does stop at break points, the data you see must be changing before your breakpoint is triggered. JavaScript is *not really* asynchronous, it just pretends to be

Comment: Where are you actually setting the breakpoint? If it is not inside the AJAX request callback then yes it could by modified by the time you go to inspect. Try making sure you are putting the breakpoint in the right callback.

Comment: I set the breakpoint in my indexeddb open call. And he stops - but he definitely also works on. I see it on many things. Timestamp for example. there is a console log just before and the time there is older than other callbacks which will show up later. Also he should stop on exceptions thrown latter as well on many "debugger" statements which gets all ignored

Comment: You may be running into https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=732524

Comment: yes, that seems likely. It is definitely a bug.

Comment: I have seen something similar where Chrome 66 was *definitely* processing a different JavaScript event, even though it was already halted at a breakpoint. In this case it was re-entering the function with the breakpoint set within it, so that was even more confusing. Sorry, I can't recall whether it was because I was using a breakpoint on a function I called using the console (different context) or because it was a breakpoint on an onmessage event (called due to iframe event so different context?). It wasn't due to an extension.